# Creating custom tracking menu clicks in Android and Apple mobile apps in GA4

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-sdk

I need some advice on how to set up tracking for a custom event for Android and IOS. We are using Firebase SDK to gather data and report to the stakeholders. I need to track the number of clicks for each menu item. I tried adding the dynamic link code but that did not work. How can track the clicks and how would I set up the code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to log custom events and associate parameters with it.

See more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android

You have two types custom events, that you can implement.

1. Recommended custom events
   Google recommends to implement these events and promise that one day it will enrich your data in GA4 UI
   https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735?hl=en
2. Custom events
   Find your own naming convention for event names, parameters. I highly recommend to create a simple documentation, be consistent.

For your case I would go with event name `navigation_click` with parameter `name`. And fill this event with item name in menu.

Remember to register this parameter in GA4 property https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en